# Why is terraform apply running very slow (10 minutes / timing out) with remote state

Tags: terraform

I'm using terraform 1.5.2 (installed via homebrew) with local execution mode and state stored in terraform cloud to run plans and applies. For the last two days, I've been encountering the following symptoms:

Long delay (a minute or more) between hitting enter on terraform plan and seeing ANY output. (so presumably not a problem talking to my AWS resources, but getting state from terraform cloud.
very long delay (5 to 10 minutes) after applying is complete, during which I see error messages saying "we're trying to restore the connection to terraform cloud".
I'm not observing unusual delays in any other steps in the process, so to my mind it appears to specifically be issues talking to Terraform Cloud

Retroactive note - I was making use of the `local_file` provider at the time that I was encountering this issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Using the `local_file` provider places multiple full copies of the file into tfstate (in my case it was ~10 copies). If these files are large, terraform takes a lot of time to download, parse and reupload the tfstate file. This causes applies to take a LONG time, and also can result in timeouts and missed applies if the LONG time becomes too long.

#### Back Story

I was using the `local_file provider` to upload a java jar file (~28mb) to an AWS Lambda function. After moving my state from terraform cloud to AWS S3 as a backend, without resolving the issues ( it was slightly better, but still way slower than it should have been) I noticed that the state file itself was 280MB. This would explain the behavior I was seeing.

I added debug logs, but the long delays in applies were between debug logs.

I refactored my code to upload the file to s3 outside Terraform, and specify just the s3 location in the lambda function Terraform code, and once I successfully applied that change the state file was back too 155kb in size, and I moved it back up to Terraform cloud and everything is great.

One other note is that I created about 10 different resources during the time I was having the connection issues; based on what happened when I switched backends, the connection issues meant that my state wasn’t being synced back to Terraform cloud.

After I found that the s3 backend was slow and the file size was large, I switched to the local backend to eliminate all network time from the process. After that it took a while to re-import resources that had created while I was having the connection issues.